# How to deploy third-part VueJS component?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, vue.js, datepicker, vuejs2

I'm trying to deploy a Vue compenent called: [bliblidotcom/vue-rangedate-picker](https://github.com/charliekassel/vuejs-datepicker#install).

So far I have done this:
Installed compenent using npm:

```
npm install vuejs-datepicker --save
```

Added these lines into app.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRangedatePicker from 'vue-rangedate-picker';
Vue.use(VueRangedatePicker);
```

Added this line to my component: `Orders.vue`

```
<rangedate-picker @events="events"></rangedate-picker>
```

However, I'm receiving:

> dash.2f99f386cf46c2486e27.js:51996 [Vue warn]: Property or method
> "events" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
> Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option,
> or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
>
> [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property
> '_withTask' of undefined"
> TypeError: Cannot read property '_withTask' of undefined

This is inside `Orders.vue`:

```
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: ['initUser'],
        data() {
            return {
                endpoint: '/approve',
                orders: [],
                btn: 'Update List',
                token: "",
                searched_term: "",
                today: false,
                from: "",
            }
        },
        computed: {....
```

This is inside `app.js`:

```
window.dashApp = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    mounted(){
        this.$root.$on('mapCreated', function (map) {
            this.currentMap = map;
        });
    },
    data() {
        return {
            currentMap: null
        }
    },....
```

Comment: Can you show code of your `Orders.vue`?

Comment: You aren't registering the component correctly. You need to add your component to the `components` object of your root Vue instance. No need to use `Vue.use`. At least that's what it says in the documentation you linked to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define handler for your event. `events` is not defined in your component. At the moment, `vue-rangedate-picker` only support selected event

[image]

```
    <rangedate-picker @selected="onSelect"></rangedate-picker>
```

in `Order.vue`

```
    import VueRangedatePicker from 'vue-rangedate-picker';

     ...
    components: {
       'rangedate-picker': VueRangedatePicker
    }
    methods: {
      onSelect(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    }
```

Comment: Now I receive: [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <rangedate-picker> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Orders> at \resources\assets\js\components\orders.vue
       <Root>

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to locally import to make it work. Please remove globally instal also.